# Does using union or joins in query causes slower performance in Sphinx?

Tags: mysql, performance, sphinx

I am willing to use **sphinx with MySQL** for my current project.
**MYISAM as database engine** as this db is gonna be only **read-only** with **10-25 millions of records**.

so i would like to know whether , 
**Does using union or joins in query causes performance issues in Sphinx ?**

as i am about to design database and if union/joins gonna cause the slower performance then i can go for optimized design for sphinx.

Maybe like creating one big table with all fields and data and then creating **separate INDEXES** in sphinx depending on the data to be searched.

please guide me in correct direction.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx cant do joins anyway. Can do unions, just searching multiple indexes at once.

Or do you mean to build the sphinx index (ie in sql_query)? Indexer will only run the queries to build the indexes in the first place.

As you say read only - hence no updates, the indexes should never rebuilding, so doesnt really matter how slow they are.

In general a sphinx index will perform very similar regardless of how many feilds. So shouldnt need to split into different indexes. JUst have one multi purpose index (if its possible).

YOu can however shard the index into bits, so can distribute to multiple servers if performance becomes an issue.

Comment: I meant, while building the Index, if i provide the mysql query with UNION and/ JOIN to join data from 2-3 tables, will it lower the speed ? or it doesnt matter as once the INDEX is built.

Comment: the sql_query, can be any arbitary query the database server is capable of running. Sphinx just runs the query directly, and indexes the results. It doesnt care how simple or complex the query is. Obvouslly more complicated queries will be harder for the database server to optimize.